# NSNumberFormatter with percent style and validation

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, xib, nsnumberformatter

I have a setup where a text field ammended with an NSNumberFormatter in my xib file. The number formatter is set to percent style (10.4+ default behavior) and got min and max values (here 0.75 and 2 for 75% and 200%). This works fine except for the validation message if the user inputs values outside this range. For instance when a 70 is entered the validation message is similar to "A value of 0.7 is too small". Obviously, since we are in percent style, the message should more like "A value of 70% is too small".

Is there anything I can do to improve the validation message in that way?